# Windows explorer get list of selected items and pass it to another process

Tags: windows, winapi, c#-4.0

I have to create File/Folder management system. In which user can select multiple files/folder and from context menu execute an command.
That command sends list of all selected files/folders list to invoke a process. So that, process can work on file/folder list.
If process is running the context menu should not shown or greyed out.

I added context menu but can't find the way to disable it. How can I do all this?
Any possible study link will help a lot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu` handler can apply whatever logic you desire to determine whether to show/hide a menu item, and if shown, whether it is enabled or disabled. Note, however, that in general, shell extensions should not be written in managed code due to CLR injection concerns.

Comment: Thanks Ray. I did with this with the help of "CSShellExtContextMenuHandler" from http://1code.codeplex.com/releases/view/62253#DownloadId=215068.